exact value of this series expansion and integral identity
is there a closed value for the series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^n}{(n!)^2}=G(x) $$
if so is this integral identity correct ?
$$ e^{-x} =\int_{0}^{\infty}G(xt)e^{-t} dt $$
i just have expanded the exponential into power series and used the borel transform of the series
to get the integral

Bessel function

The series you wrote down is $J_0(2\sqrt{x})$ where $J_0(x)$ is the zeroth Bessel function of the first kind. It indeed satisfies the integral identity you cite, which amounts to $$e^{-x} =\int_0^\infty J_0(2\sqrt{x t})e^{-t}~dt$$
To verify this result, the substitution $t=u^2$ renders the integral as $$2\int_0^\infty J_0(2\sqrt{x} \cdot u) e^{-u^2} u~du$$
Comparing this with Eq. 10.22.E51 of the DLMF, we identify $b=2\sqrt{x}$, $\nu=0$, and $p=1$ to get
$$2\cdot \frac{(2\sqrt{x})^0}{(2(1)^2)^1}\exp\left(-\frac{(2\sqrt{x})^2}{4(1)^2}\right)=e^{-x}$$
in agreement with the result obtained from power series.
